# MQ messages coming through as MQRFH2 instead of MQSTR

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

We have a ASP.NET web service that receives text and destination information and sends MQ messages from our server to another windows server using IBM WebSphere MQ Client.

We had v6 installed and everything was working fine sending messages to a server with v9.0.0.1 installed. We have upgraded our server from v6 to v9.

Messages are now being received as header type MQHRF2 when these messages are being explicitly sent as MQSTR header type.

This is likely something to do with the upgrade from v6->v9. Any ideas on what could be causing this would be very helpful as I'm at a loss.

EDIT:
Code Sample:

This is a condensed version of how we are interacting with the MQ API in our web application:

```
MQEnvironment.Hostname = "TEST_HOST";
MQEnvironment.Channel = "TEST_CHANNEL";
MQEnvironment.Port = 1414; // Default MQ Port
var queueMgr = new MQQueueManager("TEST", new Hashtable());

var openOptions = MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_SET_ALL_CONTEXT;
var queue = queueMgr.AccessQueue("QueueName", openOptions);

var message = new MQMessage();
message.ApplicationIdData = ".xml";
message.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"));
message.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
message.Persistence = MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT;
message.CorrelationId = MQC.MQCI_NEW_SESSION;

var putOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
putOptions.Options += MQC.MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT + MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;

queue.Put(message, putOptions);
queueMgr.Commit();
```

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying that: You have ASP.NET running on a Windows server somewhere and had deployed a web service on it. This web service was making use of v6 MQ Client that was talking to a v9 MQ server, and all was well. You then upgraded your MQ client to v9 and are now getting the header type mismatch ?  So the only change was in the MQ Client from v6 to v9 - correct? Are you using the XMS MQ Client?

Comment: What is the type of application receiving data?  As chughts asked are you using IBM MQ .NET or IBM MQ XMS.NET?  What specific version of the client libraries did you upgrade to?

Comment: Sounds like something is adding a message property. ALTER the queue the messages are got from to have PROPCTL(NONE).

Comment: @chughts This is correct. The only change was MQ Client (.NET) from v6 to v9 (and an application restart). No code change at all.

Comment: @MoragHughson Is this only possible via a queue change? Is it possible to make this change via a message option/property? We could potentially make this change but we do not have complete control on the queues and this seems suspect considering, in theory this shouldn't be happening as no code has changed.

Comment: Which specific version of the dll did you upgrade to?  Are you using managed or unmanaged mode? Are you using XMS.NET or just .NET?

Comment: @JoshMc our client application was originally amqmdnet.dll v6.0.2.1. Changing this to v7.5 and v9 made no difference in the behavior. I don't know the answer to your other questions as I am new to MQ but if you give me instructions I can dig out the answers.

Comment: Can you confirm if you use 6.0.2.1 dll you do not receive the MQHRF2?  Can you confirm that you are the sender or receiver of the messages?

Comment: I can confirm that I am the sender of messages only from server1. I am sending messages to another server (server2) of ours (that has MQ server 9.0.0.1 installed) and viewing these messages using MQMON. Using the v6.0.2.1 dll or v7.5 dll or v9 dll all end up sending messages of type MQHRF2. This has only happened since the upgrade to MQ v9 client on server1. Previously this was working fine with MQ v6.0.2.1 client on server1 for months.

Comment: Hi Ben, sorry for the questions, but just trying to get a better understanding.  So can you confirm if there is more than one queue manager involved, this is normally referred to as the MQ Server, if so are they all at MQ v9.0.0.1 at the queue manager side?  For the client app that runs on server1, can I conclude that it connects over the network as a MQ client to server2 where the queue manager runs?  You mention that you have upgraded server1, but then you say even when you use 6.0.2.1 dll you have the problem.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the source code on how you connect to MQ?  This would show both if you are using standard .NET or XMS.NET as well as if you are using managed or unmanged mode.  Can you provide a minimal reproducible code sample that could be reviewed?

Comment: @JoshMc see edit for code sample. No worries with the questions we are still desperate for a solution here. Server 1 is a windows 2008 R2 with MQ Client v9.0.0.1 installed (previously v6.0.2.1). Server 2 is a windows 2012 with MQ Server v9.0.0.1 installed. Server 1 has an ASP.NET web app that sends MQ messages to server 2. The web app has a code reference to amqmdnet.dll v6.0.2.1. No code change has been done. MQ client v6.0.2.1 was unistalled from server 1. V9.0.0.1 was installed on server 1 and the AppPool for our web app was recycled. Now messages are only being received as MQHRF2.

Comment: This is MQs normal .NET API not XMS.NET. Can you provide a sanitized version of the properties included in `Hashtable`? (specifically the "transport" property setting)? Do you have any servers were 6.0.2.1 is still installed where you confirm when viewing the message with MQMON that the format is correct?

Comment: Ok, I thought it was probably just the .NET API. There are no properties included on the `Hashtable`. Maybe this is the issue? No unfortunately not. However, if this is not resolved soon we will be reverting back to v6. I assume that this would work in sending the correct format as the code is consistent in this situation.

Comment: If you provide a message property handle in your code then the properties will not be part of your message buffer as an MQRFH2, and you can easily ignore them.

Comment: If `connDetails` is just a newly initialized hashtable, then how are you connecting to the queue manager on the remote "server2"?  Do you have a channel table and referencing it with env variables `MQCHLLIB` and `MQCHLTAB`, or a reference to the channel table in the `mqclient.ini` or are you using the env variable `MQSERVER` or a similar reference in `mqclient.ini`?  Based on the sample code provided I do not know of any reason why the destination when receiving a message from 6.0.2.1 would be MQSTR and from 9.0.0.1 would be MQHRF2.

Comment: @JoshMc Apologies, my mistake I forgot to include the connection method when I was condensing the code to post. See edit, we are populating the static MQEnvironment strings to connect to remote server. We did not do the actual upgrade itself, is it possible that the install of MQ Client v9 could've been configured in such a way that would create the described behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried viewing the message on the queue with a tool other than mqmon such a `amqsbcg`?

Comment: @JoshMc no I haven't but we have found the issue, see my answer for details. I appreciate your help with this and exactly as per your previous comment, under normal conditions there is no reason for this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that we have a third party tool, AppDynamics installed and running on this server. This tool is used for performance management. This tool interferes with MQ messages causing the behaviour I have details; messages being received as MQHRF2 format.

This is noted in IBM's documentation:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYHZ9_5.5.0/com.ibm.omegamon_apm.doc/troubleshooting/zapm_issues.htm

> - AppDynamics dynamically adds an MQ message property to messages to be    tracked, which is transmitted in the message via an MQRFH2
>     header.    Before you configure AppDynamics, ensure that your
>     application    programs are not affected by this modification to
>     messages. Examples    of applications that might be affected are ones
>     that expect message    content at a specific location in the message
>     without bypassing    possible extra headers in the message.

This issue can be exposed by toggling on & off the AppDynamics service on the server. With the service stopped, all messages are received in the MQSTR when send as MQSTR.

AppDynamics was already installed and running when the server had MQ Client v6 installed. This issue only started to arise when upgrading to MQ Client v9.